# How can one use the value of one field to enforce a minimum value on another field?

Tags: webforms

I'm making a registration form for an event that will have a "sliding scale" fee system, but with minimum contributions based on the size of their organisation.

I want users to be able to set the size of the organisation that is paying their fee (from very small/volunteer led up to very large, well funded organisations) via radio buttons, and then to choose their contribution using a slider. Ideally the minimum contribution a user can choose via the slider should be determined by which radio button they select.

The final contribution will then be computed using the "computed twig" field.

I've got the fields set up (including the computed twig field), but I can't work out if its possible to have a "conditional minimum" on the slider - is this possible?

Comment: If you have some code already that isn't quite working, but that you think ought to be working, you should include it in the question.

Comment: Sounds like you'll need custom JS 

Comment: If the organization some existing entity inside Drupal you may also be able to achieve it from hook_form_alter

Comment: If you share some code, we can help with more insights. HOOK_form_alter can work. Also Ajax callback can work as well.